# vmware server 2 on windows vista ultimate

Tags: vmware-server

when i click on the vmware server homepage to start the vmware server 2 app, i'm getting a page cannot be displayed instead of the popup window.

can someone please help me correct this?

i'm really fustrated because i have no idea what to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check Windows Firewall. The VMWare Server home page is a custom web site running on the host on TCP port 8333.